# What can prevent ASP.NET Session?

Tags: asp.net, session

I built a small ASP.NET application. It has a global.asax and sets some session variables on Session_Start(...).

What could prevent (all) session variables from not being set? Would a session time out do it? What if JavaScript turned off? What else can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to womp:

- Not having cookies enabled
- [Redirecting](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2004/08/03/Don_2700_t-redirect-after-setting-a-Session-variable-_2800_or-do-it-right_2900_.aspx) immediately after setting the session variable(s)

I would suspect the second one in particular, especially if you're using any sort of urlrewriting mechanism that does a Response.Redirect.

Comment: It sounds like Cookies are the culprit here.

Comment: You can change the cookieless parameter of the session state configuration element to true to force it to rewrite URLs with the session ID, if cookies cannot be re-enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Turning session off in the web.config file or machine.config file would do it (eg.  `<sessionState mode="Off" />`)

Setting `EnableSessionState="false"` in your Page directives would also do it.

Is this actually happening to you?  What do you mean "prevent them from being set".  Is Session_Start not firing?  Or it's firing, they're being set, and then they're not set later?